# Creating a class for a Flash symbol in Haxe?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe

I am having trouble incorporating graphical assets created in Flash with my Haxe code.

In the Flash IDE, I've created a symbol with the linkage name `"MySprite"`. I compile this into `assets.swf`. I know that to use symbols in this `.swf` from my Haxe code, I need to add the following option when using the Haxe compiler:

```
-swf-lib assets.swf
```

I'd now like to write a class called `"MySprite"` which is associated with this symbol, like so:

```
class MySprite extends Sprite {
    public function new() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Basically, I'd like to achieve something similar to the technique presented in [this tutorial](http://yourpalmark.com/2007/03/31/associating-custom-as3-classes-with-embedded-assets/):

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;

    [Embed(source="assets.swf", symbol="MySprite")]
    public class MySprite extends Sprite {
         public function MySprite() {
             // ...
         }
    }
}
```

It's unclear from the [Haxe documentation](http://old.haxe.org/doc/flash/0_start) whether this can be done, or what the syntax is for doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* so, but I'm not sure, Haxe doesn't override classes from `assets.swf` with the classes you declared. There was a discussion about it on the mailing list (the old one, not in the Google groups), and this was the decision... I don't know why this decision was made.

You could still do it with [SamHaxe](https://github.com/overmobile/samhaxe). At least back in the days I was able to. Unfortunately, SamHaxe was abandoned, and if there are bugs or something not working as you need it - you are pretty much on your own. The good thing about Sam is that it's relatively small project. It's written in Haxe and I was able to build it from sources.

You could also try: http://code.google.com/p/hxswfml/ The project seems to be functional and the author used to reply to users. It might be a tad more complex though. I'm quite sure it was possible to do, but you will probably need to ask the author / figure it out yourself.

Comment: SamHaXe seems to be what I need. I'll try it out and see if it works!

Comment: After examining SamHaXe, it seems like way too much overhead for what I'm after. And I don't see how hxswfml would help me here. I understand I can create swfs from XML with that tool, but that still doesn't help me associate a Symbol with a haXe class, does it?

Comment: I'm considering this question answered: you can't achieve what I was trying to do with haXe.